# Convert "if" statements into a "switch" in Swift

Tags: swift

Can you help me to convert these `if` statements into a `switch` with cases please?
I'm struggling for a while and I can't figure out how to make it work.

Here is the code:

```
class Settings: NSObject {
    let name: SettingsName
    let imageName: String

    init(name: SettingsName, imageName: String){
        self.name = name
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
}

enum SettingsName: String {
    case settings = "Settings"
    case terms = "Terms & privacy policy"
    case feedback = "Send Feedback"
    case help = "Help"
    case switchAccount = "Switch Account"
    case cancel = "Cancel"
}

@objc func handleDismiss(setting: Settings) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.blackView.alpha = 0
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }
    }, completion: { (_) in
        if setting.name == .settings {
            self.homeController?.showControllerForAccountSettings(setting: setting)
        }

        if setting.name == .terms {
            self.homeController?.showControllerForTermsAndPrivacy(setting: setting)
        }

        else if setting.name != .cancel && setting.name != .settings{
            self.homeController?.showDummyControllerForSetting(setting: setting)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but I would declare the enumeration nested in your Settings class `class Settings {
        enum Name: String {
            case settings = "Settings",
            terms = "Terms & privacy policy",
            feedback = "Send Feedback",
            help = "Help",
            switchAccount = "Switch Account",
            cancel = "Cancel"
        }
        let name: Name
        let imageName: String
        init(name: Name, imageName: String) {
            self.name = name
            self.imageName = imageName
        }
    }`

Comment: And don't subclass `NSObject` unless you really need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to do this:

```
switch settings.name {
    case .settings:
        self.homeController?.showControllerForAccountSettings(setting: setting)
    case .terms:
        self.homeController?.showControllerForTermsAndPrivacy(setting: setting)
    case .cancel:
        break
    default:
        self.homeController?.showDummyControllerForSetting(setting: setting)
}
```